# Xamarin forms binding label get and set

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I migrated my project from MVVM Cross to Xamarin Forms and I'm trying to get the binding property of a label to appear from my webservice and it's not currently working, as it was with MVVM.
When I run the app, it shows no errors on the logs but it also doens't show any of my properties, it's just blank when it comes to the properties I've binded, like the "Title" one.

This is my XAML (Forms).

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Test.Core.Pages.DeliveryPage">
    <ContentPage.Content Title="General" Icon="">
        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">



                <Label FontSize="Large" Text="GENERAL"/>
                <Frame>
                    <Label x:Name="labelTitle" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Frame>
```

This is my CS (Forms)

```
TestResponse test;



       private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(_title); }
        }
```

And then I call it like this:

```
Title = "Title: " + "\n" + test.Title;
```

And this was when I was using MVVM:

```
 private string _title;
    public string Title 
    {
        get => _title; 
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @Arvindraja there, I've updated it, my bad.

Comment: `Title = "Title: " + "\n" + delivery.Title;` Here you are setting page title or Label text?

Comment: The label text, which will grab the text that's on my webservice

Comment: Than it should be `labelTitle= "Title: " + "\n" + delivery.Title;` not Title

Comment: it doens't let me convert type string to Xamarin.Forms.label

Comment: oh try this `labelTitle.Text= "Title: " + "\n" + delivery.Title;`

Comment: I'm actually out of the office right now, but as soon as I test it I'll let you know mate. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your ViewModel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(_title); }` should be `set { _title = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title)); }`

Comment: Did you bind your ViewModel? In your .cs page in the constructor: BindingContext = new YourViewModel();

Comment: Why are you calling `OnPropertyChanged(_title)`, the binding isn't listening for that value, you should be calling `OnPropertyChanged(Title)`, which is what MVVMCross will have been doing!

Comment: I'm not using MVVM Cross anymore, it's just the xaml and the cs now. I migrated it to Xamarin Forms. It was working well with MVVM but we have decided to migrat it to forms just to test it out

Comment: @Arvindraja you were correct mate. Set as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Thank you very much. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here you are setting page title(not label text) as below

```
Title = "Title: " + "\n" + test.Title;
```

Instead you should set Label text. Your Label is `x:Name="labelTitle"`
So try to set Label text as below

```
labelTitle.Text= "Title: " + "\n" + delivery.Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

in View model you need to set public variable in OnPropertyChanged() method like below

```
private string _title;
public string Title
{
     get { return _title; }
     set { _title = value; **OnPropertyChanged(Title)**; }
}
```